# No JSON object could be decoded. Threading Python

Tags: python, json, multithreading, oop, python-multithreading

I've been trying to make multiple HTTP request using threading.

First, I have a method that calls to an API, and that method takes a dict as an argument and returns a JSON object.  Additionally, it works perfectly fine when I run it without threading.  However, here is the code and error I get when trying to use threading.

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'C:/dict/path')
import apiModule
import threading

token = 'xxxx'
apiModule = apiModule.Module(token)

urls = [{'url': 'http://www.example.com'}, {'url': 'http://www.example.com/2'}]

data = []

for element in urls:
    thread = threading.Thread(target=apiModule.method(),kwargs=element)
    thread.start()
    data.append(thread)
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#72>", line 2, in <module>
    thread = threading.Thread(target=apiModule.method(),kwargs=element)
  File "C:/dict/path", line 54, in method
    return json.loads(r.content)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
     raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try `thread = threading.Thread(target=apiModule.method, kwargs=element)`.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @falsetru's reply: According to the [threading documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html):

> `target` is the callable object to be invoked by the `run()` method

In your example you pass `target=apiModule.method()`, immediately invoking the method "`method`" on `apiModule`. This raises the error you're seeing. Currently the code is not even reaching the `thread.start()` call.

Comment: Now I'm getting the following error: ''' Exception in thread Thread-7:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 554, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 507, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable'''